# conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character to string in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, where-clause

I had a table where the service_date was char(8), like 20191007. I did a `convert(date,service_date)` as new_date and it seemed to convert it to date data type. When I try and use `convert(date,service_date) >= '2019-10-07'` I get the "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character to string" error. What do I need to change to get it to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the table schema and full command run.

Comment: Use try_convert(date,service_date) .   I suspect you have some bogus data.  try_convert will return a NULL rather than throwing an error.   To identify the problem records... SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE where  try_convert(date,service_date)  is NULL

Comment: The perils of not using a date and time data type to store a date and/or time value; people store values that aren't valid date and time values. I highly recommend fixing your data model.

Comment: Fix your model +1. Store the date in a date field. **Don't try to solve a problem that should not even exist.** You should get better performance too (noticeable on big datasets) and better utilization of indexes if present. And more flexibility if you want to show dates in different formats.

Comment: Unfortunately the data comes from my states department of human services so I have no say in how it is stored.

Comment: Then your first issue is to figure out what to do with values that cannot be converted to real dates. Once you address that, the appropriate path to your goal can be identified. Obviously, there is some issue with the data you get. Might be multiple formats or just plain bad (e.g., '20200000' or 'null'). You can use try_cast to find the problem rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string format in which you are storing your dates makes it possible to filter against a sring literal, so I would just use:

```
service_date >= '20191007'
```

This is more efficient than using a conversion function, since it can take advantage of an index on the column, if any.

However, as commented by John Cappelletti, this might produce unexecpted results if your data is not in the right format. In that case, use `try_cast()`:

```
try_cast(service_date as date) >= '20191007'
```

`try_cast()` attempts to convert the string to the target datatype, and yields `null` if the conversion fails.

Comment: This would pickup alpha strings and bogus dates as well.    OP made the tragic mistake of storing dates as strings.   service_date could contain anything... even Jan 12 1970  which is >= '20191007'

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: yes, reading through the comments that's a good point. I updated my answer to suggest `try_cast()`.

Comment: Just another thought, you could use BETWEEN   '20191007' and '20201231'